# Create .Net Project using Compact Framework files?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, compact-framework, desktop-application, windows-embedded-compact

Can that can be done so I'm generating desktop Framework binaries?

I'm assuming .net full version has most if not all CF libraries.

Comment: .NET compilers mostly create IL executables. As long as you are not using CF-only assemblies or functions/classes, the executable will run on desktop too.

Comment: @josef What are "IL executables?"  It sounds like I'd just need  to replace CF only functions and classes if they are there.

Comment: If you have the code, you'd want to search for `[DllImport]` attributes -  Windows Desktop has multiple different dll's (_user32.dll_, _kernel32.dll_, etc) but in WindowsCE all functionality is in _coredll.dll_. Besides that, you should be able to add all code files (.cs) to a new desktop project and run it.

Comment: Normal CF apps not referencing any CF-only stuff will run without changes. Just double click the exe file on your windows PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way for sure to convert over CF to .NET instead of manually looking at where dependencies are in CF in what few extra libraries CF has that .NET does not.